# Wildcard SSL - Apache and Tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate

We currently run 4 onsite web servers and 1 offsite server. Four of our severs run Apache 2.x webservers, while the one other server runs Tomcat.

The server which runs on Tomcat contains third party software, and we can't change it to Apache.

We have one domain name, and several subdomains pointing to each of the servers. For instance:

```
sd1.domain.com - Apache Server - Windows
sd2.domain.com - Apache Server - Windows
sd3.domain.com - Tomcat Server - Windows
sd4.domain.com - Apache Server - Linux
```

As you can see (in my crude example), although the server software changes, the domain name still points to the servers.

My question is, we are looking into purchasing a wildcard/multi-server SSL certificate. Will I only need to purchase one certificate for all servers, two certificates for windows/apache or three certificates for apache/tomcat?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single wildcard certificate for `*.domain.com` will suffice.  Certificates don't care what kind of server is being used.